# How was I supposed to reply?

Tags: grammar

I am an indian.
Today I called a receptionist.
She told me that I must submit my form by today.
I was shocked and so I said "**What?Today itself?**"
She said  "Yes today **only**"
I know both of us are wrong grammatically.Natives dont say today itself/today only.So what I(and She) should have said?

Comment: I would have said, "Today?! Ok, what time today?"

Comment: Time was not a problem,day is.Please suggest a phrase similar to meaning of my phrase.

Comment: I agree time was not your current problem, but I can speculate that it would have been your next one.

Comment: *What? This very day?* ... but as @Jim says, simple *Today?!* is quite sufficient.

Comment: I agree with @Jim; if "day" is the problem, "time" is almost invariably also a problem, as "by today" can mean _before midnight, before closing time, by sunset_, or _before bedtime_ – it all depends on what the definition of "day" is.

Comment: Guys I think its because I am just translating from my mother-tongue.We say something similar to "today only?" but I guess there is no english equivalent of it.Another eg.Boss : Mr Singh, please post this letter. It is very important.
Mr Singh : Yes Sir, I will post it today itself.  (in some case people are seen using ‘now only’, ‘today only’)Any alternative?

Comment: I think in everyday English, one is more likely to simply say "Today?" with added emphasis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Today only" means "Today is the only day that you can submit it."  You will often find it in advertising: "Today only!  All fish at half price!"

Comment: So do you think I and she used it correctly?

Comment: Today itself isn't correct in my opinion.  Today only is.  (Sorry!)

Comment: :Is 'today only' correct?I thought that it was wrong

Comment: I don't.  :)  It is pretty informal, though.

Comment: I guess the natives will never need it!       http://indlish.in/now-only-today-itself/

Answer (score 4):

I would think any of these would work:

> "Really? By the end of today?"
>
> "Really? Tomorrow will be too late?"
>
> "Really? Before the end of the day?"

Of course, this opens another can of worms; namely, **when is the end of the day**?

*Midnight* is one valid answer, but *before closing time* might also be correct, particularly in an office setting. When the latter applies, you can also use:

> "Really? Before close of business?"

In email exchanges, you might see that written as "before COB today."